# The correct way to handle GET or POST requests in the admin panel

Tags: plugins

I am developing a plugin that is going to be used internally (inside the admin panel only).

I wonder what is the correct way to build the requests (action, params, etc) and what hook to use to be able to catch those requests. Can somebody help?

Comment: [`admin_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/) is your guy or `if( is_admin() && ( !defined('DOING_AJAX') || !DOING_AJAX ) ) { # catch'em }`

Answer (score 1):

*You should post some code examples, explaining what are you trying to do, to get more useful answers.*

There are various hooks, and the one you should use depends on **what** you need. Anyway, here [Codex: Actions Run During an Admin Page Request](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request) and here [Codex: Administrative Actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions) the codex list the hooks to use for admin panel requests.

Example: If you have to activate something in the admin initialization, you can use the `admin_init` action hook, so the code will be: `add_action('admin_init', 'your-custom-function');` If you have to operate when a page load in the dashboard, you can use the `load-(page)` hook; for example: `add_action('load-post.php', 'your-custom-function');` and so on.

You can manage GET and POST requests  with `$_GET['x']` and `$_POST['x']`, where `x` is the variable you want to take from the query string. Example:

```
wp-admin/post.php?post=69
$_GET['post'] == 69
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much, but I like this way.

For forms:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_action">
```

Backend

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_my_action', 'myhandler' );
add_action( 'admin_post_my_action', 'myhandler' );

function myhandler(){

    // Do magic :)
    print_r($_POST);

}
```